# How can I invoke a sub-class of UIPickerView inSwift

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have a ViewController with a UIPickerView as a single control myPickerView which is of a class MyPickerView which I created as a sub-class of UIPickerView. I invoke myPickerView in ViewController viewDidLoad by myPickerView.viewDidLoad. However, this does not execute the source functions of MyPickerView.

I need a clarification of how I can make this work. My reason for MyPickerView is that it has a lot of special code that I did not want to clutter up the main ViewController. See the example code below:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var myPickerView: MyPickerView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myPickerView.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}


import UIKit
var gSep = ","
class MyPickerView: UIPickerView , UIPickerViewDataSource,     UIPickerViewDelegate {
var pickerData = [[" "],[" "]]
var category = [""]
var subCategory = [""]
var dictMenuList = [String:String]()

//MARK:- category/subcategory picker


func viewDidLoad() {
    println("MyPickerView: viewDidLoad")

    dictMenuList = ["Medical":"Sub-Cat 1.1,Sub-Cat 1.2,Sub-Cat 1.3,Sub-Cat 1.4,Sub-Cat 1.5,Sub-Cat 1.6,Sub-Cat 1.7",
        "Taxes": "Sub-Cat 2.1,Sub-Cat 2.2,Sub-Cat 2.3,Sub-Cat 2.4",
        "Bills": "Sub-Cat 3.1,Sub-Cat 3.2,Sub-Cat 3.3,Sub-Cat 3.4,Sub-Cat 3.5,Sub-Cat 3.6,Sub-Cat 3.7"]

    println("MyPickerView dictMenuList: \(dictMenuList)")



    self.reloadAllComponents()

    let firstKey = self.loadPickerWithCategory(0)
    self.loadPickerWithSubCategory(firstKey)

}


func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    println("MyPickerView: numberOfComponentsInPickerView \(pickerData.count)")
    return pickerData.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerData[component].count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if component == 0 {
        let selectedKey = category[row]
        loadPickerWithSubCategory(selectedKey)
    }
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return pickerData[component][row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView
{
    var pickerLabel = UILabel()
    pickerLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    pickerLabel.text = pickerData[component][row]
    pickerLabel.font = UIFont(name: pickerLabel.font.fontName, size: 17)
    pickerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    return pickerLabel
}

func loadPickerWithCategory (row: Int) -> String{
    println("loadPickerWithCategory")
    category = [String](dictMenuList.keys)
    println("MyPickerView: category: \(category)")
    if category.isEmpty {
        return ""
    }
    let n1 = dictMenuList.count
    pickerData[0].removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    for i in 0 ..< n1
    {
        pickerData[0].append(category[i])
    }
    return category[row]
}

func loadPickerWithSubCategory (key: String) {
    println("MyPickerView: loadPickerWithSubCategory")
    let x = dictMenuList[key]
    subCategory = x!.componentsSeparatedByString(gSep)
    let n1 = subCategory.count
    pickerData[1].removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    if subCategory.isEmpty {
        return
    }
    for i in 0 ..< n1
    {
        pickerData[1].append(subCategory[i])
    }

    self.reloadAllComponents()
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `viewDidLoad` is a view controller method, not a view method. A `UIPickerView` is a subclass of `UIView`, not `UIViewController`, so the system will not call your `viewDidLoad` method.

You need to override one or more of the init methods.

If you're loading your picker view from a Storyboard or XIB, you probably want to override initWithCoder.

If you're creating your picker in code, you probably want to override initWithFrame.

I sometimes create a method `setup` that I call from both `initWithCoder:` and from `initWithFrame:`. That way my setup code gets called regardless of how the view object is loaded.

I vaguely remember reading that there is a better way of handling this dueling initializers problem in Swift, but I don't remember what it is. (I'm still learning Swift.)

### EDIT:

It just occurs to me that you can use the method `awakeFromNib` to do setup after your view has been loaded and all of it's outlets are set up. That's roughly equivalent to the `viewDidLoad` call for view controllers. I should have thought of that sooner.

(`awakeFromNib` is a method of NSObject, so it's a bit hard to find if you don't know it exists.)

Comment: See the edit I just made to my answer. `awakeFromNib` is probably a better choice for a `UIView` equivalent of the `viewDidLoad` method in view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `viewDidLoad()` is a method of the `UIViewController` class and is called after the controller's view is loaded into the memory. Read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLoad). You can not use it in views.

So you should implement an `init` method inside your custom picker class. I'd recommend to override `initWithFrame` and `initWithCoder` and set up your component there.

And you will initialize your custom picker like this:

```
myPickerView = MyPickerView(frame: yourFrame)
```

Comment: Duncan, flashadvanced: Thank you for very important comments. I understand that viewDidLoad is not appropriate for a view. I changed the name to loadPicker as a way to create an array. I used storyboard to place the picker in the view of the ViewController. I am not creating the instance programmatically. Why am I not getting the picker filled? I do see an empty frame. The source functions are not recognized as evident from the println functions not executing.

Comment: Actually the connections to delegate and source are not connected (as seen in the connections inspector) which explains the problem I am having. I added self.delegate = self and self.dataSource = self in the loadPicker and it connected. Thank you all for your help.